# Python: Logic to to pick a variable for a number

Tags: python

I'm creating a smart home system in domoticz and I'm having some issues. So basically I have 32 relays for connections (ON, OFF) and each of one is displayed as a switch (In domoticz). Every switch has his own idx number for API control (turn on/off the switch with requests). My task is to get the status of my relays, for example I can only get 1,0 these are on/off. 1 is equal to on, 0 is equal to off. So I built a little logic to get the relay status, but then I realized that the idx numbers are unique to every device I have, and they are mixed. So I built some type of define, but I don't know how to work with it.

These are my definitions for every relay. This is only an example, these are not my real idx's from domoticz.

```
# Relays
RELAY_1_IDX = 1
RELAY_2_IDX = 2
RELAY_3_IDX = 3
RELAY_4_IDX = 4
RELAY_5_IDX = 5
RELAY_6_IDX = 6
RELAY_7_IDX = 7
RELAY_8_IDX = 8
RELAY_9_IDX = 9
RELAY_10_IDX = 10
RELAY_11_IDX = 11
RELAY_12_IDX = 12
RELAY_13_IDX = 13
RELAY_14_IDX = 14
RELAY_15_IDX = 15
RELAY_16_IDX = 16
RELAY_17_IDX = 17
RELAY_18_IDX = 18
RELAY_19_IDX = 19
RELAY_20_IDX = 20
RELAY_21_IDX = 21
RELAY_22_IDX = 22
RELAY_23_IDX = 23
RELAY_24_IDX = 24
RELAY_25_IDX = 25
RELAY_26_IDX = 26
RELAY_27_IDX = 27
RELAY_28_IDX = 28
RELAY_29_IDX = 29
RELAY_30_IDX = 30
RELAY_31_IDX = 31
RELAY_32_IDX = 32
# Inputs
INPUT_1_IDX = 50
INPUT_2_IDX = 51
INPUT_3_IDX = 52
INPUT_4_IDX = 53
INPUT_5_IDX = 54
INPUT_6_IDX = 55
```

This is my code without any logic to give the number a definition.

```
# Change 32 Relays statuses to real-time in domoticz.
for relay in range(1, 32):
    RELAY_INPUT = f"RELAY-READ-255,{relay}"
    srvsock.sendto(RELAY_INPUT.encode(), (edsIP, edsPORT))

    _relay_status_ = srvsock.recv(4096).decode('utf-8').replace(f'RELAY-READ-255,{relay},','').replace(',OK', '')
    _set_ = Domoticz.set_value(relay, int(_relay_status_))

    # _relay_status_ is an integer, available - 1,0 (1-on, 0-off)
    # ... Logic to find idx number for the current relay which is our for bool....

    if _set_ is False: print(f'* Note: Request for relay {relay} was unsuccessful.')
    time.sleep(0.15)
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear (well, in fact there's no question mark in your post, so it's hard to see if there is an actual question in it)

Comment: @Demi-Lune I need to pick a idx number from defines to the current relay in the bool.

Comment: @FlairskullGT its better you store those relay information in some sort of data structure like `list` or `dict` instead of variable name so that you can efficiently access them. For your answer look for `eval()` function.

Comment: You see if I would use eval(), I would still need to put every IDX define that I wrote and there would be many if functions...

Comment: As I can see, `RELAY_IDX` are numbers. So, why use them when you can use `relay` value isntead?